# using jsftp to upload files results in files of zero size on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm trying to put files on my server with jsftp. Everytime I run my code I do get a file written to the server but it has 0 bytes. I'm certain that the user: host: etc are correct.

Here's the code.

```
function uploadHours() {
var jsftp = require("jsftp");

var ftp = new jsftp({
host: localStorage.host,
port: Number(localStorage.port), // defaults to 21
user: localStorage.user, // defaults to "anonymous"
pass: localStorage.ftpPass // defaults to "@anonymous"
});

ftp.auth(localStorage.user, localStorage.ftpPass, function(hadErr) {
if (!hadErr)
alert("auth succesfull")
});
;
ftp.put('C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe After Effects CC 2014/Support Files/Hours Tracker/index2.html', '/public_html/indexTester2.html', function(hadErr) {
  if (!hadError)
alert("File transferred successfully!");
});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I needed to read the file first. Here's what worked.

```
 var JSFtp = require("jsftp");    
 var fs = require("fs");
 var Ftp = new JSFtp({ 
     host: localStorage.host,
     port: Number(localStorage.port),
     user: localStorage.user,
     pass: localStorage.ftpPass
 });
 var local = filePath;
 var remote = localStorage.ftpPath + logName;
 fs.readFile(local, function(err, buffer) {
     if(err) {
         console.error(err);
         callback(err);
     }
     else {
         Ftp.put(buffer, remote, function(err) {
             if (err) {
                 console.error(err);
                 callback(err);
             }
             else {
                 alert(file + " - uploaded successfuly");
                 callback();
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.(using jsftp to upload files results in files of zero size on vsftpd server)

make sure use console.error to print the error.

```
Ftp.put(buffer, remote, function(err) {
         if (err) {
             console.error(err);
             callback(err);
         }
         else {
             alert(file + " - uploaded successfuly");
             callback();
         }
     });
```

the error like that

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT **192.168.0.4:64953**]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.0.4',
  port: 64953 }
```

because of my vsftpd using the PASV model,so when it return the port .jsftp modified the ip .I resolve this problem :
modify jsftp.js (jsftp/lib/jsftp.js)

```
var fixhost;

var Ftp = module.exports = function(cfg) {
    ...
    this.useList = cfg.useList || false;
    fixhost=this.host;//add
}

 Ftp.prototype.getPasvSocket = function(callback) {
    ...
    options.host=fixhost;//add
    var socket = self._pasvSocket = Net.createConnection(options);
}
```