# jsftp uploading crappy Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, node-modules

today I've got a problem with jsftp.
When I'm running my script and `upload.txt` is empty,
jsftp is correctly uploading an empty file to the server.
When `upload.txt` is a utf-8 javascript file for example `const x = "Hello World!";`,
jsftp is uploading a file named `.pureftpd-upload.5e35d750.15.79c5.1b3bbd87` with 0 bytes (= no data).

Here's my script:

```
var ftp = new jsftp({
            host: "ftp.example.url",
            port: 21,
            user: user.name,
            pass: user.pass
        });
        ftp.auth(user.name, user.pass, function(err){
            if(err){
                openDialog();
                console.error(err);
                throw err;
            }
            else{
                ftp.put(path_datafile, '/directory/hello.js', function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                    throw err;
                });
            }
        });
```

(There are no errors in the output)

For the people saying you need to read the file first:

```
var ftp = new jsftp({
            host: "ftp.example.url",
            port: 21,
            user: user.name,
            pass: user.pass
        });

        fs.readFile(path_datafile, 'utf8', function(err, buff){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                ftp.put(buff, '/directory/hello.js', function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                    throw err;
                });
            }
        });
```

Didn't worked at all.
Then it is showing the error:

```
Local file doesn't exist
```

The error here is that the `fs` module is now converting the file
to utf-8 `fs.readfile(file, 'utf8', action)`.
To solve that problem, only write `fs.readfile(file, action)`,
so that the file is outputted in bytes.
The script will output `false` but work fine.

So Ragnar is right.
His answer is correct, when you aren't using `utf8` encoding with fs.
Don't use it and it will work.

Ragnar:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052928/ragnar

His Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939160/12470434

Comment: Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939160/4173464 you must read the file

Comment: debug your path_datafile with concole.log(path_datafile).